# Angular 4 animation giving error as "no exported member '?DomAnimationEngine'"

Tags: angular

I need to work on Angular 4 animation so i followed the usual steps like importing the BrowserAnimationsModule module in the root module and importing it in the component. I have also installed npm modules but I am getting an error as

```
node_modules/@angular/animations/browser"' has no exported member '?DomAnimationEngine'
```

Please let me know what i need to do to solve it.

Comment: we need to see code where you actually use the `DomAnimationEngine`

Comment: Below is the entire error that i am getting ERROR in /node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animatio
ns/src/providers.d.ts (8,119): Module '"/node_modules/@an
gular/animations/browser"' has no exported member '?DomAnimationEngine'.
webpack: Failed to compile.

Comment: In the providers.d.ts file it is giving error at import for DomAnimationEngine. Can you please confirm where should i export it??

Comment: I was having similar issues and I was able to resolve the compile issue by upgrading to 4.2.0 if you're aren't already on it.  I was following the ionic upgrade procedure to 3 and post said to use 4.1.3

Comment: I deleted and reinstalled all my node modules and its working now. @getbuckts anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check your package.json file, and remove the ^ from the **angular/animations** dependency:
before:

```
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
```

after:

```
    "@angular/animations": "4.1.3",
```

then delete your node_modules folder and run

```
npm install
```

If it doesn't work try following the issue recommendations on https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17400

I had the same problem, and after some struggling it worked.

Comment: For me it was "@angular/animations": "^4.4.7", I changed it with "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3", and worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: thanks, I needed to downgrade animations to similar version as angular was! :)